# Caller Side unable to shows preview in pjsua 2

Tags: c++, ios, pjsip, videocall

I tried different ways but didn't succeed. the following is the code I use for the display preview window.

```
void MyCall::onCallMediaEvent(OnCallMediaEventParam &prm)
{
    if (prm.ev.type == PJMEDIA_EVENT_FMT_CHANGED) {
        try {
            CallInfo info = getInfo();
            try {
                VideoPreview preview(info.media[prm.medIdx].videoIncomingWindowId);
                VideoWindow window = preview.getVideoWindow();
                VideoWindowInfo window_info = window.getInfo();
                if (!window_info.isNative) {
       
            }
                MyTimerParam *tp = new MyTimerParam();
                tp->type = TIMER_START_PREVIEW;
                tp->data.start_preview.dev_id = 1; // colorbar virtual device
                tp->data.start_preview.hwnd   = &window;
                tp->data.start_preview.w      = 320;
                tp->data.start_preview.h      = 240;
                tp->data.start_preview.fps    = 15;
                updateVideoPtr(&window);
                // Schedule the preview start to be executed immediately (zero milisecond delay).
                Endpoint::instance().utilTimerSchedule(0, tp);
            } catch(Error& err) {
            }
        } catch(Error& err) {
        }
    }
}
```

It crashes while reaching **window_info.** Kindly help me on getting a preview window.

I'm trying to set the video on the preview window but it will not appear